# What type of clip/clamp?

Tags: mounting

I have been looking for days for a certain type of clip/clamp and I cant find the name of it. It is basically like this photo below (same size) but flat. It almost looks like a razor blade. It is mostly mounted on the wall with a screw and you push one side which sends the clip teeth up. I've seen it mostly used to add support for curtains. I am looking for an inconspicuous/small clip/clamp that I could mount on a wall to hang some fabric. Any help or alternative suggestions is appreciated, Thank you. Just trying to find something small and inconspicuous so it doesn't stick out too much when the fabric isn't up.

It does a similar job as these clips
[image: It has the same function as these clips] but looks more like a razor like this[image]

Comment: The top ones are pipe or wire clamps but how you think they look like a razor...

Comment: @Solar Mike i am trying to find a clamp that I previously seen but cannot find the name. It os a push clamp like the first pic but looks like the razor in thecsecond clip. It screws into a wall.

Comment: Would something like a spring steel frame clip be close?

Comment: I think we need to know a lot more about how it looks like a razor.

Comment: @Micah Montoya seems close thank you fir the suggestion

Comment: @harper its the shape/size as a razor. Obviously no blade. It just has another layer on which acts as the clip.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is called a "paper rail" or a "display rail". There are lots of different styles, here is one:

[image]